# Why AsyncStorage will return "null" with react native?

Tags: react-native, expo, asyncstorage

Now, I am making a mobile app with react native and expo and try to use AsyncStorage to store a set of key and value.
However, I can get "null" from AsyncStorage.get('key');

The code below is my code about apart of using AsyncStorage.

```
async checkQrUrl(data) {
const asyncStorageKey = JSON.stringify(data);

if (this.state.couponType === 'once') {
  try {
    if (data === this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('qrcodevancoupon001shop', 'aaa');
      Alert.alert('一回切りのクーポンを使用しました');
    } else if (data !== this.state.UniqueQrUrl) {
      Alert.alert('QRコードが違います');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('予期せぬ障害が発生しました。前画面に戻って再度お試しください');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
}
```

In addition to this code, below one is to get key.

```
async componentDidMount() {
const { value } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
await AsyncStorage.getItem(`qrcodevancoupon001shop`, (result) => {
  this.setState({ couponModalStatus: result });

});
```

}

Comment: `const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('qrcodevancoupon001shop');` Put it in the variable name and return it.

Comment: I did ! Thank you so much.
But I am wondering why that is happened ?

Comment: The optional callback function type is void.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please select the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('qrcodevancoupon001shop');`

Put it in the variable name and return it.

```
this.setState({ couponModalStatus: value });
```